# How to run bash command as a diffrent user?

Tags: linux, bash, su

I am logged into as root However, I am trying to run a java program from a bash script using a different user named marshell. I get the following error not sure what is it I am doing wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su marshell <<'EOF'
CP=/home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/ # The classpath to use
java -cp $CP JavaRunCommand $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 ${10}
EOF
```

Updated:

```
#!/bin/bash
su marshell <<EOF
CP=/home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/US_SOUTH/YP/DataWorks/free
java -cp "$CP" JavaRunCommand "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}"
EOF
```

Error:

```
root@devopsops:bash runbash_marshell.sh https://api.xyz.net user@gmail.com pass AllServices test Data free data-monitor Y00 UKLONDON

runbash_marshell.sh: line 5: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:308)
bash: line 2: EOF: command not found
```

Comment: Though I can't find the acutal error, you musn't quote `EOF` if you need your positional parameters expanded. Anyway, This is a better approach: `java -cp $CP JavaRunCommand "$@"` and don't forget to unquote `EOF` in your case: `sudo su marshell <<EOF`

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` if you are already logged in as root?

Comment: runbash_marshell.sh: line 5: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF') ................ bash: line 3: EOF: command not found @j.a. I did update my code as suggested and it does work but i still see the above warning not sure why ?

Comment: why are you using `sudo su` instead of just `sudo -u`?

Comment: I have added the updated script in my question

Comment: ah! sorry the next time i was running the script from user marshell instead of root so i was getting the warning message. However, i ran it as root and it now works fine.Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad for that. Remember to use `"$@"` instead of `"$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}"`. Literally `"$@"`.

Comment: @j.a. any specific reason to use $@ instead of "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}" ? Since it works when i use "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "${10}". I tried "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" "$@" how will it understand which parameter to use when ?

Comment: I mean just a unique `"$@"`, it's easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the command flag `-c` for su like

`> foo=bar; su marshell -c "./suc $foo"
 bar`

where the script just prints all parameter passed to it.
In your specific case it should look something like

`> su marshell -c "CP=/home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/; java -cp $CP JavaRunCommand $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 ${10}"`

or

`> sudo -u marshell -i "CP=/home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/; java -cp $CP JavaRunCommand $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 ${10}"`

For sudo you could use something like parameters `-u` and `-i`.

```
-u user     The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified
               command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid
               instead of a user name, use #uid.  When running commands as
               a uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a
               backslash ('\').  Security policies may restrict uids to
               those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy
               allows uids that are not in the password database as long
               as the targetpw option is not set.  Other security policies
               may not support this.

-i [command]   The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell
               specified by the password database entry of the target user
               as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource
               files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.
               If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for
               execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is
               specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts
               to change to that user's home directory before running the
               shell.  The security policy shall initialize the
               environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what
               is present when a user logs in.  The Command Environment
               section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i
               option affects the environment in which a command is run
               when the sudoers policy is in use.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the parts which should be passed through verbatim.  If your command-line arguments are `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `quux`, and you want Java to execute

```
java -cp "$CP" JavaRunCommand foo bar baz quux
```

then you need to interpolate the command-line arguments, but quote (the dollar sign in) `$CP` so it is not being interpolated by the current shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su marshell <<EOF
CP=/home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/ # The classpath to use
java -cp "\$CP" JavaRunCommand $@
EOF
```

This will unfortunately *not* properly quote any arguments containing spaces.

A much better approach would actually be

```
sudo -u marshell java -cp /home/marshell/sanity_test_scripts/ JavaRunCommand "$@"
```